# Adding vertices with chosen weight in a vertex group - Python

Tags: python, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I would like to add vertices in a vertex group with a weight already set by python.

For example a button that set weight force to the selected vertices to 0.5:

row.operator ("object.vertex_group_assign", text=" 0.5")